# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem new Form CreateHandle Deadlock

Tags: winforms, multithreading, deadlock, handle

I have a thread that needs to create a popup Window.
I start the thread using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CreatePopupinThread))
Thew thread creats a new form. The application freases in the new Form constructor at CreateHandle. The Worker Thread is locked...
How can I fix this?

this is how I create the form

```
var form = new ConfirmationForm
                           {
                               Text = entry.Caption,
                               Label = entry.Text,
                           };
```

In the constructor the thread enters a deadlock

```
public ConfirmationForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Comment: suggest you post your code (cutdown but exhibiting behavior)

Comment: Avoid doing any UI Operations in the background (secondary) thread, they should be done on main thread. This will most of the times avoid deadlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem...
The deadlock whas triggered because the tread start whas done in a Form Activated Event... I have moved it to a Shown event and now it works ok...

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to create the "popup window" on the UI thread and then create a thread in the "popup window" to process what you want it to do.

As I suspected, you can´t show a form created on a non ui thread.
See this answer: [Possible to construct form on background thread, then display on UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073076/c-winforms-possible-to-construct-form-on-background-thread-then-display-on-ui/2073349#2073349)

Comment: it is not that simple... the thread is actualy a "user code". The user can enter c# code that is compiled at runtime and it is runed at certain events.. This "user code" has some misc methods and one of them popups a message...

Comment: " The user can enter c# code that is compiled "...please NOOOoooo!

Comment: You can perfectly well create a form on a new thread as long as it is a STA one.