# Unable to Threading in a method which sets some class properties

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to apply thread s in a method which sets some properties. but after applying threading the method stops setting the values. My code :

Class Page.cs

```
public int numOfResults { get; private set; }

public int perPage { get; private set; }

public int pageCount  { get; private set; }

public void pageResults()
{
    HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument document = htmlWeb.Load(this.url);

    var totalResults = document.DocumentNode
                               .Descendants("div")
                               .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
                                           x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("result-totals"));

    string totalPages = string.Empty;

    foreach (var result in totalResults)
    {
        if (result.InnerHtml != null)
        {
            totalPages = result.InnerHtml;
            totalPages = totalPages.Substring(totalPages.LastIndexOf("f") + 1, 4);
            numOfResults = Convert.ToInt32(totalPages.Trim());
        }
    }

    var resultsSet = document.DocumentNode
                             .Descendants("div")
                              .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
                                          x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("business-container-inner"));

    perPage = 0;
    foreach (var result in resultsSet)
        if (result.InnerHtml != null)
            perPage++;

    pageCount = (numOfResults / perPage) + 1;
}
```

calling:

```
Pages htmlDoc = new Pages(url);
Thread MyThread = new Thread(htmlDoc.pageResults);
MyThread.Start();
lblTotalRecords.Text = "Records Found : " + htmlDoc.numOfResults.ToString();
lblTotalRecords.Visible = true;
lblTotalPages.Text = "Pages Found : " + htmlDoc.pageCount.ToString();
lblTotalPages.Visible = true;
```

Before applying Thread all the values were setting properly but now all their values are set to 0.

Comment: What's the point of doing it in a separate thread? Seems that you need to wait for your thread to finish before assigning the *lblTotalRecords*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to read `numOfResults` and the other variables right after the `MyThread.Start();` call. The thread, however, could be in any one of the several possible [thread states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at this point - it *may* even be finished, although that's probably the least likely outcome.

When you try to get data about the completion of a thread you have a few options:

- Use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it has an event that signals that the thread is done with its work. It's also simple to use.
- Create a dedicated class that implements the thread function and also declares an event when it's done.

Using `BackgroundWorker` is likely the simpler solution in your scenario (since you're trying to update `Label` controls). The other solution is something like this:

```
public class MyThreadWorker
{
    public event EventHandler<MyDoneEventArgs> Done;

    // TODO set input parameters through constructor or public properties

    public void DoWork ()
    {
        // TODO process work
        // TODO raise Done event
    }
}
```

Here are a few other SO links with more detail (no point in repeating them so I only link them here):

- [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)
- [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)
- [Thread is not staring while calling a function called by other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150447/thread-is-not-staring-while-calling-a-function-called-by-other-thread/14150686#14150686)

Comment: thank you very much for your time and suggestion. but i'm still confused how can i get the values the properties ? Please guide me.

Comment: thank you very much. these links helped me a lot. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

Use the MyThread.Join() method to wait for the thread to finish. Join is a blocking function and wait till completion. You can provide timeout duration to Join after which it will yield.